# How can I check for software versions in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have two software version checks in my bash script that don't work as I would have expected.

```
DRUSH_VERSION="$(drush --version)"
echo ${DRUSH_VERSION}
if [[ "$DRUSH_VERSION" == "Drush Version"* ]]; then
    echo "Drush is installed"
  else
    echo "Drush is NOT installed"
fi
GIT_VERSION="$(git --version)"
echo ${GIT_VERSION}
if [[ "GIT_VERSION" == "git version"* ]]; then
    echo "Git is installed"
  else
    echo "Git is NOT installed"
fi
```

Response:

```
Drush Version : 6.3.0
Drush is NOT installed
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
Git is NOT installed
```

Meanwhile, if I change

> DRUSH_VERSION="${drush --version)"

to

> DRUSH_VERSION="Drush Version : 6.3.0"

it responds with

> Drush is installed

For now I will use

> if type -p drush;

but I would still like to get the version number.

Comment: `"GIT_VERSION"` should be `"$GIT_VERSION"` in the second `if`. With that fix, that check works for me. I don't have "drush". Try `echo "${DRUSH_VERSION}"` (with the quotes) to see if there is funny whitespace in there.

Comment: @Nemo the git check is now working, but the Drush check is not.  I do echo ${DRUSH_VERSION} and it prints without issue.

Comment: No you echo it unquoted. Put quotes around it like in my comment. Otherwise the shell will split on whitespace, passing multiple arguments to `echo`, which can fool you.

Comment: Are you sure the Drush version comes from your `echo`? If it prints to stderr you would see the output anyway, but your `echo` would produce an empty line. Anyway, if this hunch is correct, the fix is easy; just add a `2>&1` redirection.

Comment: @tripleee If the `echo` wasn't producing the code, there would be a blank line in the output, since `echo $DRUSH_VERSION` would imply print a newline.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, exactly.

Comment: You can also try using `*"Drush Version"*` to see if any leading whitespace is causing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues you can fix. First, if you are not concerned with portability, then you want to use the substring match operator `=~` instead of `==`. That will find `git version` within `git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)`. Second you are missing a `$` in your `[[ "GIT_VERSION" == "git version" ]]` test.

So, for example, if you change your tests as follows, you can match substrings. (**Note:** the `=~` only works with the `[[ ]]` operator, and you will need to remove any wildcards `*`).

```
if [[ "$DRUSH_VERSION" =~ "Drush Version" ]]; then
...
if [[ "$GIT_VERSION" =~ "git version" ]]; then
...
```

Additionally, if you are just checking for the existence of a program and not the specific version number, then you are probably better off using:

```
if which $prog_name 2>/dev/null; then...
```

or using a compound command:

```
which $prog_name && do something found || do something not found
```

E.g. for `git`:

```
if which git 2>/dev/null; then
...
```

or

```
which git && echo "git found" || echo "git NOT found"
```

**Note:** the redirection of `stderr` into `/dev/null` just prevent the error from spewing across the screen in the case that `$prog_name` is NOT present on the system.

Comment: `[[` is already non-portable, so switching to `=~` won't cost anything.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to refer it as a variable like `${DRUSH_VERSION}` instead of `"$DRUSH_VERSION"` in if condition.